# How to use Entity Framework include with condition?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose that we have two entities, *Posts* and *Comments*. *Posts* has a navigation property to *Comments* and vice versa:

```
public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
```

And also *Comments* has a navigation property to *User*:

```
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

Now, how to query all *Posts* including only the last comment (by comment creation date) and the user who created it?

Comment: show the code you have tried

Comment: @Mak to load all posts with all comments including user simply we do:
_db.Posts.Include(p => p.Comments.Select(p => p.User)).ToList();
but because of performance issues I want only the last comment with user who creates that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible with the current version of EF but you can vote for it here https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/47