# Linq to select top 1 related entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How can I include a related entity, but only select the top 1?

```
    public EntityFramework.Member Get(string userName)
    {
        var query = from member in context.Members
                    .Include(member => member.Renewals)
                    where member.UserName == userName
                    select member;
        return query.SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: I guess you desire conditional include this feature doesnt exist in EF so far you can upvote here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/47

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Entity Framework include with condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380345/how-to-use-entity-framework-include-with-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN:

"Note that it is not currently possible to filter which related entities are loaded. Include will always bring in all related entities."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232

There is also a uservoice item for this functionality:

http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015345-allow-filtering-for-include-extension-method

The approach to use an anonymous object works, even though it's not clean as you wish it would be:

```
    public Member GetMember(string username)
    {
        var result = (from m in db.Members
                    where m.Username == username
                    select new
                    {
                        Member = m,
                        FirstRenewal = m.Renewals.FirstOrDefault()
                    }).AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Member).FirstOrDefault();

        return result;

    }
```

The FirstRenewal property is used just to make EF6 load the first renewal into the Member object. As a result the Member returned from the GetMember() method contains only the first renewal.

This code generates a single Query to the DB, so maybe it's good enough for You.